# Can airplane aluminium be used in low altitude rocket? (1km)

Tags: rockets, engineering

Can aluminium which is using in airplane construction be used in rocket?

I consider, 1km is not altitude where resistance can destroy some parts of important rocket. Most probably rocket impulse will be 30-60 seconds with 2 metres of height of whole rocket.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't even high power rocketry (<230 Ns). Usually people build these kind of rockets from cardboard. Building model rockets from aluminium is frowned upon because of the military feel and the relatively high [ballistic coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_coefficient) at least in Germany. If you want to build such rockets get in contact with your local rocketry club (AGM or Solaris in Germany for example). We are always happy about newcomers.

Comment: @Christoph, I am from Azerbaijan, and there are no rocket clubs :D Is cardboard enough for this rocket?

Comment: And maybe you know which type of fuel recommended to this kind of rocket? I am thinking about rocket candy, but afraid that it is not enough (

Comment: There are a lot of airplanes flying much higher than 1 km.

Comment: @uhoh, okay, thanks. Can you recommend any rocket construction platforms? (Christoph's Germany forum is in Germany, not enough material in English:( )

Comment: @Aga that would be a good question for the chat room of this site (scroll to the bottom of this page and look for `Chat`).

Comment: 1km is within the realm of hobbyist rockets, unregulated in the US.  Cardboard is the normal material, aluminum would be unacceptable for safety reasons.  While I've never sent one that high others in the group I launched with did.

Comment: @uhoh: AFAIR, during the site definition phase, we decided amateur rocketry is on-topic.

Comment: @uhoh: Recent additions were about *not helping people get themselves blown up*. In particular, no amateur liquid fuel engines, especially cryofuels, hypergols, strongly toxic stuff like hydrazine etc.

Comment: @uhoh: I think if your balloons had rocket propulsion they would be on-topic too. Both without cubesats and without crossing the Karman line. I'd say everything about rocket propulsion is on-topic (although overly suicidal themes are not to be encouraged.) For all we know, Aga could be asking for tips on building missiles here; as long as he doesn't start asking about warheads or target-seeking, his question is still on-topic.

Comment: @SF. looks like all is well. I've clean up comments not related to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, there is no reason not to use aluminium. From the comments, cardboard is the standard material and aluminium could be against safety rules (due to uncontrolled landings, potentially on your head). Check your local regulations.

To see if aluminium is technically possible, the altitude is not important, speed is.

In airplanes, aluminium is usable up to cruise speeds of about Mach 2.2 (at high altitudes). Above that, the airframe heats up too much and the aluminium will start to soften. But it takes time for the fuselage to heat up, so you can get away with higher speeds for short flights.

Comment: Yes. Also, the heating is mostly concentrated to leading edges.

Comment: In amateur rockets, the heating is mostly concentrated around the combustion chamber... The amateur rockets use simple ceramic mixes (plaster, brick powder with some adhesive etc) for the parts most exposed to combustion, and/or just accept partial ablation/combustion of the motor structure. Aluminum is a "luxury" material, quality, but also risky (if something blows up, the pressure and resulting destructive effects will be much worse; a cardboard rocket exploding on the launchpad won't do much harm.